# Voltage drop on motor controlled by arduino via transistor

Tags: arduino, transistors, motor

I am using a transistor (TIP 122) to control a dc motor using arduino. Although the power source I use is measured at 6V, I only get 5V at DC motor(M1) when I use the transistor. Here is the schematic:

[image]

Is this voltage drop normal or do I miss something?

Comment: Did you even *look* at the datasheet for the TIP122?  Also, you need to know the current that the motor will draw.

Answer (score 2):

Some voltage drop there is normal; you want to saturate the transistor to minimise the voltage drop, and to increase that saturation you need to increase the base current.

Your "transistor" is not actually a transistor but a Darlington pair according to the datasheet extract Dzarda posted, which means it has unusually high gain (hFE=1000) and they quote saturation voltages at Ic/Ib=250.

The downside of a Darlington is higher Vce than a singlo transistor, since Vce cannot fall below Vbe of the second transistor, or about 0.6 to 0.7V.

But note the Ib values : 12mA for Ic=3A, and 20mA for Ic=5A. That's quite a bit higher than the 5mA you can get from an Arduino pin through a 1k resistor. So there is some scope to reduce Vce by increasing base current (R1=470R or 330R) but if 0.6V is still too much, then either:

- replace the Darlington with a single transistor (probably with a second transistor to increase Ib. Saturation is usually about 0.2V at Ib = Ic/10, so if the motor takes 1 Amp you need Ib=100mA)
- use a MOSFET as Dzarda suggests

Answer (score 1):

This voltage drop is indeed normal. BJT transistors have intrinsic drops in them originating from their construction. The [datasheet](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/TI/TIP120.pdf) says the following:

[image]

Also, on page 3 the graph labeled
"*Figure 2. Base-Emitter Saturation Voltage and Collector-Emitter Saturation Voltage*"

So, depending on the operating conditions, you can get up to 4V of drop across the CE terminals (during saturation ~ the "ON" state).

Such high drop is really not suitable for 6V of supply voltage. Get a MOSFET, they behave much more like variable resistors.

Comment: I have used a MOSFET in the past using this wiring http://grobotronics.com/images/detailed/5/Arduino_Mosfet.jpg , but the voltage drop was similar. Anyway, since I am not doing anything wrong, I will use a higher power supply. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

When the base of a transistor is made high then it should behave like a short circuit. But, unfortunately most of the transistors have a little voltage drop. So it is very normal according to your circuit.
You can use L293d motor driver chip. The voltage drop will be less than 1volt.